# how to mapping join type by using spring data elasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

i reindex data from es 2.4 to 5.6.
data in es 2.4 have 2 types,and the 2 type is parent-child relation.
when reindex it to es 5.6,the index only contains single type,the parent-child relation by using join type to resolving.
the data above works ok.
the mapping example like this, it contains a join type:

```
"mappings": {
    "doc": {
        "properties": {
            "my_join_field": {
                "eager_global_ordinals": true,
                "type": "join",
                "relations": {
                    "question": "answer"
                }
            },
            "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "ignore_above": 256,
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

how to mapping join type by using spring data elasticSearch:
in old version code es 2.4,i can mapping it like this:

```
@Document(indexName = ParentEntity.INDEX, type = ParentEntity.PARENT_TYPE, shards = 1, replicas = 0, refreshInterval = "-1")
public class ParentEntity {

    public static final String INDEX = "parent-child";
    public static final String PARENT_TYPE = "parent-entity";
    public static final String CHILD_TYPE = "child-entity";

    @Id
    private String id;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text, store = true)
    private String name;

    public ParentEntity() {
    }

    public ParentEntity(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new ToStringCreator(this).append("id", id).append("name", name).toString();
    }

    @Document(indexName = INDEX, type = CHILD_TYPE, shards = 1, replicas = 0, refreshInterval = "-1")
    public static class ChildEntity {

        @Id
        private String id;
        @Field(type = FieldType.Text, store = true)
        @Parent(type = PARENT_TYPE)
        private String parentId;
        @Field(type = FieldType.Text, store = true)
        private String name;

        public ChildEntity() {
        }

        public ChildEntity(String id, String parentId, String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.parentId = parentId;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getParentId() {
            return parentId;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return new ToStringCreator(this).append("id", id).append("parentId", parentId).append("name", name).toString();
        }
    }
}
```

how can i Mapping join type by using spring data elasticSearch v3.0.10?

Today, i tried the entity below to working  at spring data elasticSearch 3.0.10:

```
@Document(indexName = "join_index", type = "join_mapping")
@Data
public class JoinEntity {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Mapping(mappingPath = "/mappings/join_type.json")
    private Map<String,String> relationType;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String name;
    //@Parent(type = "question")
    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String parentId;
}
```

join_type.json below:

```
{
  "type": "join",
  "relations": {
    "question": "answer"
  }
}
```

it create index and put mapping work ok:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:elasticsearch-template-test.xml")
public class ElasticsearchTemplateJoinTests {

    @Autowired
    private ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        clean();
        elasticsearchTemplate.deleteIndex(JoinEntity.class);
        elasticsearchTemplate.createIndex(JoinEntity.class);
        elasticsearchTemplate.putMapping(JoinEntity.class);
        elasticsearchTemplate.refresh(JoinEntity.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldCreateIndexAndMappingSuccess(){
        Map mapping = elasticsearchTemplate.getMapping(JoinEntity.class);
        assertThat(mapping, is(notNullValue()));

        Map properties = (Map) mapping.get("properties");
        assertThat(properties, is(notNullValue()));

        assertThat(properties.containsKey("name"), is(true));
        Map file = (Map) properties.get("relationType");
        assertThat(file, is(notNullValue()));
        assertThat(((String) file.get("type")), is("join"));
    }
}
```

when index parent work ok too,but index child it throws exception:

```
@Test 
public void shouldIndexParentAndChildSuccess(){
    JoinEntity parenEntity = new JoinEntity();
    parenEntity.setName("parent_name");
    parenEntity.setRelationType(Collections.singletonMap("name","question"));
    IndexQuery parentQuery = new IndexQueryBuilder().withId("11").withObject(parenEntity).build();
    final String id = elasticsearchTemplate.index(parentQuery);
    assertThat("11",is(id));
    JoinEntity childEntity = new JoinEntity();
    childEntity.setName("child_name");
    Map<String,String> joinRelation = new HashMap<>(2);
    joinRelation.put("name","answer");
    joinRelation.put("parent", "11");
    childEntity.setRelationType(joinRelation);
    childEntity.setParentId("11");
    IndexQuery childQuery = new IndexQueryBuilder().withId("22").withObject(childEntity).build();
    elasticsearchTemplate.index(childQuery);
}
```

exception:

```
MapperParsingException[failed to parse
]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[[routing] is missing for join field [relationType]];
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.wrapInMapperParsingException(DocumentParser.java:171)
```

how can i resolve this problem or Mapping the new version Parent-child relation  correctly?thks!!

Comment: Did you find a way to do it? I'm wondering how to do it as well

Comment: i reindex them by two index, thus it will adapt future version,Some advanced and immature features suggest a reduction in usage

Answer (score 2):

Elasticsearch needs the parent document routing parameter when you index child document [check this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html)

This is because both parent and child documents must be indexed in same shard to join to work.

However I couldn't figure out a way to solve this using Spring data elasticsearch. The only way that worked was using **RestHighLevelClient**

The recent version of Spring Data ElasticSearch had added support for this [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#reference)

Your child indexing would be something like,

```
    IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest();
    indexRequest.source(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(childEntity),XContentType.JSON);
    indexRequest.id("22"); //child doc id
    indexRequest.index(INDEX_NAME);
    indexRequest.type(INDEX_TYPE);
    indexRequest.routing("11"); //parent doc id
    restHighLevelClient.index(indexRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i gived up the parent-child relation, i split them into two separate indexs. some advance feature should be used less if not neccessary.